# schematron: can I group namespaces

Tags: namespaces, prefix, schematron

our content has stuff from around 8 different namespaces. In my schematron rule below I am just checking in one of them. I want to do the rule  to check elements in 6 of them but not the other 2, I'm not sure the best way to do this. I am thinking it would be good to group the 6 namespaces and give them one single prefix and then use that. Is it possible to do this?

```
<pattern>
    <rule context="def:para | def:para-text | def:block | def:quote-para | def:source-para | def:note-para" role="warning">
        <report test="text()[contains(.,'www.')]">URLs should be marked up with a url tag</report>
    </rule>
</pattern>
```

Comment: Thanks both these answers are very helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following construct:

```
*:ElementLocalName[namespace-uri()='http://namespace.tld']
```

If you're using XSLT2, you could declare a variable near the top of your schema like this:

```
<sch:let name="my6namespaces" value="('http://ns1.com', 'http://ns2.com', 'http://ns3.org', 'http://ns4.com, 'http://ns5.net', 'http://ns6.com')"/>
```

Then you can use it in your rule:

```
<pattern>
    <rule context="*:para[namespace-uri()=$my6namespaces] | *:para-text[namespace-uri()=$my6namespaces] | *:block[namespace-uri()=$my6namespaces] | *:quote-para[namespace-uri()=$my6namespaces] | *:source-para[namespace-uri()=$my6namespaces] | *:note-para[namespace-uri()=$my6namespaces]" role="warning">
        <report test="text()[contains(.,'www.')]">URLs should be marked up with a url tag</report>
    </rule>
</pattern>
```

If it doesn't hurt performance too much, you could shorten the rule context like this:

```
<pattern>
    <rule context="*[local-name()=('para', 'para-text', 'block', 'quote-para', 'source-para', 'note-para') and namespace-uri()=$my6namespaces]" role="warning">
        <report test="text()[contains(.,'www.')]">URLs should be marked up with a url tag</report>
    </rule>
</pattern>
```

Note, your rule as currently written will generate a successful-report whenever one of those elements has "www." in it. I think you might have intended to write it as an `assert` rather than a `report`, in which case it would generate a failed-assert whenever one of those elements *doesn't* have "www." in it.

Comment: Thanks Joshua, this is exactly what I meant. I will use this frequently I think. Although on this particular occasion I have just followed the first suggestion as it will do the job for me today. The report type is correct, www should always be within a url instead of loose in a para etc.

Comment: Now that I re-read your <report>, it makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 0):

In XML, you can't map multiple namespace URIs to the same prefix at the same time. The whole point of namespaces is to disambiguate same-named elements (and attributes) from different vocabularies, so they didn't provide a way to conflate multiple namespaces.

Untested, but you could match on the elements in any namespace then test only elements that are not in the unwanted namespaces:

```xml
<pattern>
    <rule context="*:para | *:para-text | *:block | *:quote-para |
                   *:source-para | *:note-para" role="warning">
        <report test=".[not(self::a:*) and not(self::b:*)]/text()[contains(.,'www.')]"
          >URLs should be marked up with a url tag</report>
    </rule>
</pattern>
```

It's not clear from your question whether same-named elements can appear in multiple namespaces. The code above assumes that the same local name can be used in any namespace, and that the 'a' and 'b' prefixes are mapped to the namespace URIs of the namespaces that you don't want to test.